# How to run cgi scripts in tomcat in Windows system

Tags: perl, apache, cgi, tomcat6

I installed tomcat and removed the comments of cgi script in web.xml in conf folder
Now iam not able to understand where to place my cgi script 
I have read many resources and i placed it in a Webapps/Myfolder/WEB-INF/cgi/hello.cgi
here hello.cgi is my sample cgi script
I also typed the following in Webapps/Myfolder/WEB-INF/web.xml

`

```
<web-app>
   <servlet>
    <servlet-name>cgi</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.catalina.servlets.CGIServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>debug</param-name>
      <param-value>0</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>cgiPathPrefix</param-name>
      <param-value>WEB-INF/cgi</param-value>
    </init-param>
     <load-on-startup>5</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

`

Now iam not understanding where should i map my cgi script here
I am not getting any idea what exactly this web.xml does
Can any one provide a solution how can i do this.